# How to pass array element by reference in c++?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to pass a single array element by reference (so that the argument passed in is modified)?
For example, say this is a main part:

```
int ar[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
test(&ar[2]);
```

And now this is the function definition:

```
void test(int &p)
{
    p = p + 10;
    return;
}
```

The above code results in a compilation error.

Comment: You should include the errors you are receiving.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`&ar[2]` takes the *address* of the element at the 3rd position in the array. So you try to pass an `int*` to an function expecting an `int&`. Typically you don't need to do anything to an expression to make it be treated as a reference, since a reference is just another name for some object that exists elsewhere. (This causes the confusion, since it sometimes seems to *behave* like a pointer).

Just pass `ar[2]`, the object itself:

```
test(ar[2]);
```

Maybe it will be clearer if you put the array to one side for a moment, and just use an `int`.

```
void test (int &p);
// ...
int a = 54321;
test(a); // just pass a, not a pointer to a
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to provide an alternative to BobTFish's answer. In case you need to pass an address, then your function definition needs to accept a pointer as an argument.

```
void test(int *arg);
// ...
int arg = 1234;
test(&arg);
```

and to use the address of an array element you do the following:

```
void test(int *arg);
// ...
int arg[0] = 1234;
test(&arg[0]);
```

Some people add parenthesis to the array element: `&(arg[0])`, which is fine when in doubt, But the `[]` operator has higher precedence than the `&` operator.